# Friendly_ID only returns one object, when many match the find criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, friendly-id

I have a column called `ticker` on my `PortStock` model. I have setup friendly_id so I can use vanity URLs, i.e. it can use the ticker as the ID rather than the ID itself.

The issue is that a user can have many `port_stock` objects that have the same `ticker` value. But `friendly_id` is not returning all of them in the standard `friendly.find` call.

For example:

```
    [15] pry(main)> cac = cu.port_stocks.friendly.find("CAC")
      PortStock Load (3.1ms)  SELECT  "port_stocks".* FROM "port_stocks" INNER JOIN "portfolios" ON "port_stocks"."portfolio_id" = "portfolios"."id" WHERE "portfolios"."user_id" = $1 AND "port_stocks"."ticker" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 2], ["ticker", "CAC"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
    => #<PortStock:0x00007ff143b53768
     id: 14,
     portfolio_id: 1,
     stock_id: 58,
     volume: 250,
     transaction_price: 8.0,
     current_price: 8.0,
     action: "sell",
     position: "closed",
     ticker: "CAC">
```

However, if I query for all the `port_stocks` with that same `ticker` value, I get 6 objects:

```
[16] pry(main)> cu.port_stocks.where(ticker: "CAC").count
   (3.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "port_stocks" INNER JOIN "portfolios" ON "port_stocks"."portfolio_id" = "portfolios"."id" WHERE "portfolios"."user_id" = $1 AND "port_stocks"."ticker" = $2  [["user_id", 2], ["ticker", "CAC"]]
=> 6
[17] pry(main)> cu.port_stocks.where(ticker: "CAC")
  PortStock Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "port_stocks".* FROM "port_stocks" INNER JOIN "portfolios" ON "port_stocks"."portfolio_id" = "portfolios"."id" WHERE "portfolios"."user_id" = $1 AND "port_stocks"."ticker" = $2  [["user_id", 2], ["ticker", "CAC"]]
=> [#<PortStock:0x00007ff143b33e68
  id: 14,
  portfolio_id: 1,
  stock_id: 58,
  volume: 250,
  transaction_price: 8.0,
  current_price: 8.0,
  action: "sell",
  position: "closed",
  ticker: "CAC">,
 #<PortStock:0x00007ff143b33d28
  id: 2,
  portfolio_id: 1,
  stock_id: 58,
  volume: 250,
  transaction_price: 7.4,
  current_price: 8.0,
  action: "buy",
  position: "open",
  ticker: "CAC">,
 #<PortStock:0x00007ff143b33be8
  id: 15,
  portfolio_id: 1,
  stock_id: 58,
  volume: 30,
  transaction_price: 7.95,
  current_price: 8.0,
  action: "sell",
  position: "closed",
  ticker: "CAC">,
 #<PortStock:0x00007ff143b33aa8
  id: 3,
  portfolio_id: 1,
  stock_id: 58,
  volume: 45,
  transaction_price: 7.8,
  current_price: 8.0,
  action: "buy",
  position: "open",
  ticker: "CAC">,
 #<PortStock:0x00007ff143b33968
  id: 16,
  portfolio_id: 1,
  stock_id: 58,
  volume: 125,
  transaction_price: 7.9,
  current_price: 8.0,
  action: "sell",
  position: "closed",
  ticker: "CAC">,
 #<PortStock:0x00007ff143b33828
  id: 10,
  portfolio_id: 1,
  stock_id: 58,
  volume: 125,
  transaction_price: 6.5,
  current_price: 8.0,
  action: "buy",
  position: "open",
  ticker: "CAC">]
```

What could be causing this?

Shouldn't `friendly_id` return all objects that match that query?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your second query method is correct. The friendly find slug unique.

From the [documentation](http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/file.Guide.html#Uniqueness)...

It states...

> When you try to insert a record that would generate a duplicate friendly id, FriendlyId will append a UUID to the generated slug to ensure uniqueness:

```rb
car = Car.create :title => "Peugeot 206"
car2 = Car.create :title => "Peugeot 206"

car.friendly_id #=> "peugeot-206"
car2.friendly_id #=> "peugeot-206-f9f3789a-daec-4156-af1d-fab81aa16ee5"
```

So I'm sure if you looked at your slugs in your `PortStock` model, (if you were using the `ticker` as your slug in your model)...

```rb
friendly_id :ticker, :use => [:slugged, :finders]
```

you will find many records with the UUID appended to your slugs. In your case, calling `friendly.find("CAC")` is the same as calling `find(14)`.